# Simple past of present perfect?

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I wonder which one is correct:

> 1. David has made a decision to quit his job in spite of good salary.
> 2. David made a decision to quit his job in spite of good salary.

I think that 1 is correct, cause we want to focus on David's action, but my friends say that 2 is correct.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Both could be correct, depending on the context. What exactly are you trying to emphasize and to whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two questions:

1. Has David decided to quit his job even though it pays well?
2. Why did David decide to quit his job even though it pays well?

The imaginary question dictates the tense of the answer. (Also, I would use the verb "decide" rather than the prolix "make a decision")